# Compare two matrices, keeping values in one matrix that are TRUE in the other

Tags: r, matrix

This seems to be an easy task, which I am not finding a solution on R after looking up here and elsewhere. I have two matrices, one with string values and another with logical values.

```r
a <- matrix(c(
              "A", "B", "C"
              ))

b <- matrix(c(
              T, F, T
              ))
```

```
> b
      [,1]
[1,]  TRUE
[2,] FALSE
[3,]  TRUE
> a
     [,1]
[1,] "A"
[2,] "B"
[3,] "C"
```

I need to create a third matrix that keeps values in the first that are TRUE in the second, and leaving NA on the remainder, like so:

```r
> C
      [,1]
[1,]  "A"
[2,]  NA
[3,]  "C"
```

- How do I achieve the above result?

Comment: Something like this? c <- matrix(a[ifelse(b, T, NA)], ncol = ncol(a))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
C <- matrix(a[ifelse(b, T, NA)], ncol = ncol(a))
```

Comment: I particularly like this (though I'm not supposed to say so in comments), is the first `ifelse` I've seen in a subset position like this, and being on the LHS seems would be more stable that the RHS assign-like options (purely subjective). And was only on second viewing that I appreciated the `a[ifelse(b` aspect in its entirety. And matrix. Wonderful.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative by just assigning the NA to FALSE:

```
a[b==FALSE] <- NA
```

```
     [,1]
[1,] "A" 
[2,] NA  
[3,] "C"
```

Comment: Or use `replace(a, !b, NA)`

Answer (score 1):

using which:

```
c<-a
c[which(b==FALSE)]<-NA
```

Answer (score 0):

a <- a[b] . This might also work, Depending on how you want the result.

Comment: I tried this, but it loses the NA.